# Continue the execution of a loop after an exception is raised

Tags: python, django

```
for item in r.get_iterator():
    if 'retweeted_status' in item:
        print('aa')
    else:
        id_twitty = item['id']
        count_ret = item['retweet_count']
```

if `item['id']` throws a `KeyError` exception the execution terminates.

How to make the `for` loop continue its execution after the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try and catch the `KeyError` exception that gets raised and then discard it:

```
for item in r.get_iterator():
    if 'retweeted_status' in item:
        print('aa')
    else:
        try:
            id_twitty = item['id']
            count_ret = item['retweet_count']
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean infinite output error?

Comment: try as you have added another
except:
                              print ("error" + str (KeyError))
                              pass

but after discovering the error gives infinitely error. 

In try:

I have the more cycles

Comment: it would be more helpful if you posted the exact code that causes this problem.

Comment: Thank you all, great post code. Thanks to your answers he found a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to `EAFP` style, you can apply `LBYL` and use [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) if `id` not found in `item`:

```
for item in r.get_iterator():
    if 'retweeted_status' in item:
        print('aa')
    elif 'id' not in item:
        continue
    else:
        id_twitty = item['id']
        count_ret = item['retweet_count']
```

Comment: I prefer try/catch in these scenarios, if only because then I don't have to worry about a possible race condition when one might apply. Any time I try to retrieve information, I do so at the same time I check that it exists. Presumably in this case, there is no such race condition, but.....

Comment: @AdamSmith yup, I usually ask for forgiveness too, well depending on a use case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could either check first if `item['id']` exists:

```
for item in r.get_iterator():
    if 'retweeted_status' in item:
        print('aa')
    else:
        if 'id' in item:
            id_twitty = item['id']
            count_ret = item['retweet_count']
```

Or use `None` if it doesn't exist:

```
for item in r.get_iterator():
    if 'retweeted_status' in item:
        print('aa')
    else:
        id_twitty = item.get('id')
        count_ret = item['retweet_count']
```

Or use some other default value if it doesn't exist:

```
default_id = 0

for item in r.get_iterator():
    if 'retweeted_status' in item:
        print('aa')
    else:
        id_twitty = item.get('id', default_id)
        count_ret = item['retweet_count']
```

Comment: I like this too, because it opens the door for easy logging. `if id_twitty is None: logging.warn("id_twitty did not exist for {}".format(repr(item)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in r.get_iterator():
    if 'retweeted_status' in item:
        print('aa')
    else:
        id_twitty = item.get('id', None)
        count_ret = item.get('retweet_count', None)
        if not id_twitty or not count_ret:
            print "could not retrieve id or count"
            # handle error here
```